Frege on truth?
According to my memory, Frege wrote an article or a book where he in the beginning states something to the effect that truth is the subject matter of logic. What is the name of the text, if any?

Gottlob Frege: (1918/9) Der Gedanke. Eine logische Untersuchung.
Beiträge zur Philosophie des deutschen Idealismus 2 p. 58-77. Translated English version:  Frege (1956) The thought: A logical inquiry. Mind 65:259 pp.289-311.

@GeorgEssl Please expand into an answer.

The likely sought quote is from:

Gottlob Frege: (1918/9) Der Gedanke. Eine logische Untersuchung.
Beiträge zur Philosophie des deutschen Idealismus 2 p. 58-77.
Translated English version: Frege (1956) The thought: A logical
inquiry. Mind 65:259 pp.289-311.

Quote from the English translation, 4th sentence:

To discover truths is the task of all sciences; it falls to logic to
discern the laws of truth.

German original:

Wahrheiten zu entdecken, ist Aufgabe aller Wissenschaften: der Logik
kommt es zu, die Gesetze des Wahrseins zu erkennen.

